# Only in DEBUG CONSOLE: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

VSC 1.61.2, Angular 12 app, stops at a breakpoint, I wanted to check something on a variable `myRouter` defined as `Router`, so in **DEBUG CONSOLE**, this is OK and returns something:

`this.myRouter.config`

But `var x=this.myRouter.config.map(c=>c.path)` or simply `var x=this.myRouter.config` received

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'config')

Same statements in .TS file below all work. Curious why.

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
...
constructor(private myRouter: Router, ...){}
...
var x=this.myRouter.config.map(c=>c.path);
...
```

Comment: @Drenai updated.

Comment: @Drenai no improvement but thank you very much for the input!

Answer (score 0):

I think I've seen something like this before.... in the editor it may be displayed as `this.myRouter`, but if there's an outter function (especially an arrow function) it's possible that `this` may have been replaced with `_this` (or something similar) when the code was transpiled.

When the breakpoint is hit, have a look at the `variables` panel and expand the `closures` that precede the current `local` variables to see if it's the case here